# Quick and securely send a file from one computer to another in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, security, encryption, file-upload

I've read some articles and posts on how to go about sending a file from one computer to another in Python 3.x as well as how to encrypt the message (file in this case). I successfully recreated the scenario I wanted and managed to send an encrypted file, but I would like to do it in the most effective way possible. So what is some good libraries to use if one wants to encrypt a file with the security of at least AES-256 and best speed possible? So my question is, what would be an optimal Encryption strength to file transfer speed ratio? What libraries encrypt the fastest, with a reasonable security, and sends it as quickly as possible?

Comment: Don't ask for libraries, it's off-topic. Read [help] for more details.

Comment: What am I supposed to ask for then? One library can be very different from another in terms of speed but can accomplish the same thing. I asked for a library (a method). Also I asked for a library since building all of it from scratch seem rather unnecessary...

Comment: Did you read the article @user202729 linked to? [It explains](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the rationale thusly: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: What have been done: A program in python 3.x that encrypts a message in AES-256 and sends it to another computer. Problem: what is the most efficient and secure way of doing this?

Comment: For transfer - could you just use a secure channel, such as https, ftps, sftp or ssh? Much easier, out of box, battle-proven. If you go for encryption speed, find a library supporting AES-NI (e.g. pycryptodom ). However - finding a tool is considering offt topic, voting to close the question

Comment: I'm looking for a good method, and the method exists in a tool. Voting for you to get some education :)